# How can I request standard pop-up "use current location" with plist?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

When I run first time my app it asks me "Would you like to use your current location?" I called this pop-up with `[СLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];`. Can I request this pop-up using plist or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by using a plist - a plist is a data structure, not an event or method.
When you start the CLLocationManager, it needs to check with the user if it can use the device's current location.  If the user has already answered "NO" to the "use current location" question twice, it will not ask anymore.  This setting is stored on the device, and can be reset in the Settings app.

But this dialog is spawned and controlled by the os, so you cannot invoke it any other way.

You can, however, write your own pop-up message with any contents you like any time you like, using UIAlertView.

Comment: I thought if I write in plist something like UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities:GPS - it will call pop-up "use current location". But this isn't true.

Comment: That flag is for preventing your app from starting if the required capability is not there (i.e. if phone required, won't start on an iPad).  See this doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1397/_index.html  -- What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: [СLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] - is a single way to ask the user if he want using your current location. I thought that I can do this with plist parameters. However, this isn't true.